# How can an ExtraColumn type property be used in a Custom Control in XPages?

Tags: custom-controls, xpages, xpages-extlib

When defining the properties of a custom control in the "Property Definition" section, you can choose as "Type" in the "Property" tab the option of "extraColumn" and "iconColumn".

How should this type be used ?

Comment: Is this option "Complex Types > Icon Column" with class as `com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.data.IconColumn`?

Answer (score 1):

Both iconColumn and extraColumn relate to the corresponding tags of the dataView control. You would typically use these when your custom control contains a dataView and you wish to allow an outside control to pass in details about the columns to be used in the dataView.

Comment: But, how is it used in the DataView control ? What should I do with compositeData.myExternalDefinedIconColum contents ?

Comment: You can choose to 'hard-code' the extraColumns as shown in my answer rather than passing them in as composite data.

Comment: The ComplexType is essentially providing an interface to ensure that the format of property is consistent with that needed to define an iconColumn. InPlace of the declarative statements provided in David's answer you would simply insert compositeData.myExternalDefinedIconColumn

Answer (score 0):

When a data view is used in a standard XPage, the extraColumns appear as actual columns. The summaryColumn is the first column and shows as a link.

However, in a mobile application, extra columns show up as additional lines of data in the mobile data row. The summaryColumn value shows as "header" in the data row, while the extraColumn values show underneath that value.

```
<xe:dataView id="dataView1" pageName="#contactDetails" collapsibleDetail="true">
    <xe:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="TeamDirectoryNameLU">
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xe:this.data>
    <xe:this.summaryColumn>
        <xe:viewSummaryColumn columnName="Name"></xe:viewSummaryColumn>
    </xe:this.summaryColumn>
    <xe:this.extraColumns>
        <xe:viewExtraColumn columnName="Office" style="font-size:12pt"></xe:viewExtraColumn>
        <xe:viewExtraColumn columnName="OfficePhone" style="font-size:12pt"></xe:viewExtraColumn>
        <xe:viewExtraColumn columnName="Email" style="font-size:12pt"></xe:viewExtraColumn>
    </xe:this.extraColumns>
</xe:dataView>
```

One row of that might display as:

```
Ian Kennedy
London Office
44-22-830-6000
ian.kennedy@company.co.uk
```